# show that ${n \choose 0} - {n \choose 1} + \cdots + (-1)^n {n \choose n} = 0$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I was asked to show that this formula is true.

${n \choose 0} - {n \choose 1} + \cdots + (-1)^n {n \choose n} = 0$

I've already proven that ${n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} + \cdots + {n \choose n} = 2^n$

However, I'm not really sure if these two are related at all or if I'm missing the point here.
How do I show that this formula is true?

Comment: They are related: how did you prove the $2^n$ formula?

Comment: Hint: $2^n=(1+1)^n$, $0=(1-1)^n$.

Comment: @NickD I used a proof by induction

Comment: If you used induction, did you use Pascal's identity? Because Pascal's identity can be used to prove both. Don't forget for this identity, you have to use $n=1$ as the base case, not $n=0$ because it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is the binomial expansion of $(1-1)^n$ which is equal to zero.

Comment: There is a scope to elaborate further

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k},$$
and see what happen when $n$ is odd and $n$ is even.

Comment: When k is odd and n even?

Comment: no, when $n$ is odd, the result is obvious, but when $n$ is even, it needs more work.

Comment: oh I see, thanks!